# When did the Targaryens convert to the Faith of the Seven?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

When did the Targaryens take The Seven to be their gods? Before moving to Dragonstone, between then and the conquest, or after the conquest?

Comment: I just read something related to this in ACOK today, page 109, Davos: `Dragonstone's sept had been where Aegon the Conqueror knelt to pray the night before he sailed.` And further down the page: `Septon Barre had once told Davos how they'd been carved from the masts of the ships that had carried the first Targaryens from Valyria.` Of course, this is coming from an unreliable narrator, and it is not conclusive in any way, but somewhat interesting. From a lore perspective, I would have figured the Targs for R'hllor worshipers. The Seven being the andals' gods, not the valyrians'.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good find. I remember reading that now. So that establishes (if it's true) that they had converted at least by the time of the conquest, though whether before or after building Dragonstone is still unknown.

Comment: By the way, in the second quote "they" refer to the statues of the seven. The statues had been carved from masts of...

Answer (score 7):

In a [forum chat](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Month/2008/07/) Martin revealed that Aegon I converted to the Faith of the Seven as a political maneuver, implying that the Targaryens had not embraced the Faith until then. The question remains, however, on *when* did Aegon adopt the Faith, before he embarked on the conquest or after?

The story told by Septon Barre about Aegon praying to the Seven before he set sail from Dragonstone seems to indicate that the conversion happened before the invasion, though that is the only piece of evidence indicating this and coming from a biased perspective it's not clear if it should be trusted.

However, the theory of Aegon adopting the Faith before his landing is corroborated by the way the High Septon reacted to the invasion. When the news of the arrival of Aegon and his sisters in Westeros reached the High Septon's seat (based in Oldtown in those days) he fasted for seven days and nights looking for guidance from the Seven. Afterwards he emerged and announced that the Faith would not oppose Aegon and Oldtown followed suit and did not war on the Targaryens, and it was in Oldtown that Aegon I Targaryen was anointed the King of Westeros. This could indicate that Aegon was of the Faith when he first landed, otherwise the High Septon might not have been so easily dissuaded to support him.

Comment: Note that it only says that Aegon *prayed*, but not to whom. Later, they put the sept at the place he had prayed. It is just a trick with words by GRRM.

Comment: @TLP - Good point!